# Xamarin, MvvmCross, HotTuna, Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross

We use MVVMCross for our app implementation targeted across both Android and iOS platforms. We're also using the HotTuna Sqlite plugin (3.2.1) for Sqlite.

Recently we discovered that during the lifecycle of the app we were creating too many sqlite connections such that the app was reaching a file handle limit resulting in random connection failures (SocketExceptions) when trying to connect back to our server. To resolve the issue we decided to create a connection per table in our sqlite DB to limit the number of connections created (and therefore file handle and achieved this by creating a generic singleton for our DB access:

```
using System.Linq;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Cirrious.CrossCore;

namespace MeetApp.Shared.Services.Data
{
    public class SqliteDataService<T> : IDataService<T> where T : new()
    {
        private static object lockObject = new object();

        private static object connectionObject = new object();

        private static ISQLiteConnection _connection;

        private static SqliteDataService<T> _instance;

        public SqliteDataService(ISQLiteConnectionFactory connectionFactory, string dbPath)
        {
            if (_connection == null)
            {
                _connection = connectionFactory.Create (dbPath);
                _connection.CreateTable<T> ();
            }
        }

        public static SqliteDataService<T> GetInstance(ISQLiteConnectionFactory connectionFactory, string dbPath)
        {

            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    _instance = new SqliteDataService<T> (connectionFactory, dbPath);
                }
            }

            return _instance;
        }

        public void Insert(T value)
        {
            lock (connectionObject) {
                _connection.Insert (value, typeof(T));
            }
        }

        public void InsertAll(IEnumerable<T> values)
        {
            lock (connectionObject) {
                _connection.Insert (values, typeof(T));
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Read(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            lock (connectionObject) {
                return _connection.Table<T> ().Where (predicate);
            }
        }

        public T ReadFirst(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            lock (connectionObject) {
                return Read (predicate).FirstOrDefault ();
            }
        }

        public void Update(T value)
        {
            lock (connectionObject) {
                _connection.Update (value, typeof(T));
            }
        }

        public void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            lock (connectionObject) {
                var valuesToDelete = Read (predicate);

                if (valuesToDelete == null)
                    return;

                foreach (var value in valuesToDelete) {
                    _connection.Delete (value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem we have now is a number of crashes on Android only:

```
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (intptr,string,int,intptr&,intptr) <IL 0x0003c, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (intptr,string) <IL 0x0000f, 0x000a3>
[mono-rt]   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare () <IL 0x00011, 0x0008f>
[mono-rt]   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand/<ExecuteDeferredQuery>d__0`1.MoveNext () <IL 0x0003f, 0x0014f>
[mono-rt]   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<T>) <IL 0x0001b, 0x0018f>
[mono-rt]   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<T>) <IL 0x00031, 0x0015b>
[mono-rt]   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<TSource>) <IL 0x00007, 0x00077>
[mono-rt]   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery<T> () <IL 0x0001b, 0x000cb>
[mono-rt]   at SQLite.TableQuery`1.GetEnumerator () <IL 0x00013, 0x000a7>
[mono-rt]   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<T>) <IL 0x00001, 0x00083>
[mono-rt]   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<T>) <IL 0x00031, 0x0015b>
[mono-rt]   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<TSource>) <IL 0x00007, 0x00077>
[mono-rt]   at MeetApp.Shared.Repositories.Impl.EventRepository.GetBasicEvents () [0x00074] in /Users/edprice/development/source/bsdstudios/client/MeetApp.Client.Android/Shared/Repositories/Impl/EventRepository.cs:115


public IEnumerable<Event> GetBasicEvents()
        {
                List<Event> events = new List<Event> ();

                try {
                    var eventsFromDB = _dataServiceFactory.GetDataService<EventSql> ().Read (x => true).ToList ();

                    if (eventsFromDB != null) {
                        foreach (EventSql eventSql in eventsFromDB) {
                            Event anEvent = CreateBasicEventFromEventSql (eventSql);
                            events.Add (anEvent);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    MvxTrace.Error ("GetBasicEvents - Ex: {0} ", ex);
                }

                return events;
            }
        }
```

The forums suggest it's the result of two or more threads trying to utilise the same connection, however:

- Our sqlite setting is set to Serialized
- It affects Android only and not iOS
- We've put locks around all read and write code and we still see the same errors

I wonder whether anyone could give any advice or direction and guidance on approaches that have used MvvmCross and HotTuna Sqlite in multithreaded apps. Many thanks for your time and advice!

We're also using the HotTuna plugin which appears to be updated regularly but I notice the nugget site suggest using the communities plugin instead, even though the last update was in February? Can anyone give some guidance on this?

Comment: You might try using the newest version of the MVVMCross Community SQLite.  I don't believe there is a NuGet yet but I just had a pull accepted which updated the community version to work with 3.2.1.  You can find the project [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite)

Comment: Your stacktrace only includes `MeetApp.Shared.Repositories.Impl.EventRepository.GetBasicEvents` which isn't part of the sample code you provided. Is there any crashing sample you code could include? It's hard to comment on things like your `lock`s when the code doesn't show them (one thing that immediately comes to mind is wondering whether the `IEnumerable` actually gets enumerated inside the `lock` or not - but it's too hard to say without code... could be barking up completely the wrong tree)

Comment: Apologies, I've edited the SqlDataService code above to reflect the locks. To be clear, we still have the issues with this code, though judging by your comments above it would appear that you would expect the locks to cover the enumerations too. I've also added the GetBasicEevnts code to illustrate what we're doing.

Comment: I've same issue. Do you have found a solution?

Comment: Yes. As Stuart suggests above ensure you have locks around the enumerations.